# Create http.Response instance with sample body string in golang

Tags: http, go, response

I am willing to create a sample `http.Response` instance in golang with a sample body string.

Problem is, its body property accepts `ReadCloser` instance. But as its a dummy response instance, I was wondering if there is some trick to set it easily without setting up all that stream read/close parts.

Comment: You can extend a simple string reader or something similar with a dummy `Close` method.

Comment: Which is done for you: [ioutiil.NopCloser](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser)

Comment: Now you can use [http.NoBody](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.6#NoBody).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As suggested by [Not_a_Golfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239701/not-a-golfer) and [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb):

`io.ReadCloser` is an interface that is satisfied when a `struct` implements both the `Read` and the `Close` functions.

Fortunately, there is `io.NopCloser`, which takes  a `io.Reader` and wraps it in the `nopCloser` struct, which implements both `Read` and `Close`. However, its `Close` function does [nothing](https://go.dev/src/io/io.go#L678) as implied from the name.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    t := http.Response{
        Body: io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString("Hello World")),
    }

    buff := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    t.Write(buff)

    fmt.Println(buff)
}
```

To play with the code, click [here](http://play.golang.org/p/lLBi006Zwb).

Answer (score 25):

Further to the top answer, I have found that in order for the response to be treated as the genuine article by clients, it needs to be more fully formed. For a normal (200) response, I do the following:

```
body := "Hello world"
t := &http.Response{
  Status:        "200 OK",
  StatusCode:    200,
  Proto:         "HTTP/1.1",
  ProtoMajor:    1,
  ProtoMinor:    1,
  Body:          ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString(body)),
  ContentLength: int64(len(body)),
  Request:       req,
  Header:        make(http.Header, 0),
}
```

Then you can, for example, add headers (with a 401 status code, to ask for authorisation, say). `req` is the `http.Request` for which you are generating the response.

Answer (score 3):

This should work..

```
func main(){

    go serveHTTP(*port, *host)

    select {}
}

func serveHTTP(port int, host string) {

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        requestHandler(w, r)
    })

    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%d", host, port)
    server := &http.Server {
        Addr:           addr,
        Handler:        mux,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

    err := server.ListenAndServe()
    log.Println(err.Error())
}

func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  fmt.Fprintf(w, `Success!`)
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `ioutil.NopCloser` is just what I needed!

Am trying to test a method that performs calls to the facebook API (via a helper function) for a social-connect endpoint, and I want to mock the facebook response coming from the helper function, so my solution is like follows:

Expected facebook response (converted to my own `UserData` struct) is:

```
UserData {
    ID:        facebookID,
    Email:     email,
    FirstName: firstName,
    LastName:  lastName,
}
```

So I create the expected response like this:

```
fbUserData, _ := json.Marshal(UserData{
    ID:        facebookID,
    Email:     email,
    FirstName: firstName,
    LastName:  lastName,
})
fbUserDataResponse := &http.Response{
    Body: ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString(string(fbUserData))),
}
```

Then I can mock the response for the method calling the facebook API like this:

```
s.fbGateway.EXPECT().ExecuteGetQuery(userUrl).Return(fbUserDataResponse, nil).Times(1)
```

The point here is that this is really about mocking any kind of functions that return `*http.Response` data (in my case I am calling the facebook API via a helper function that returns the http Response, as mentioned above).